# Graph won't start at zero

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm working on a Dashboard, and I'm trying to display daily sales on a graph using mongodb. The issue that I'm having is that my graph does not start at 0, instead it starts at a number closer to the lowest number of daily sales that I entered. Also, the graph only displays the two dates that had sales, and I was wondering if there was a way to include all dates in between and following those dates? I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

OrderRouter.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import Order from '../models/orderModel.js';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import {isAdmin, isAuth, isSellerOrAdmin, mailer, payOrderEmailTemplate} from '../utils.js';


orderRouter.get(
  '/summary',
  isAuth,
  isAdmin,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const dailySales = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%m-%d-%Y', date: '$createdAt' } },
          orders: { $sum: 1 },
          sales: { $sum: '$totalPrice' },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    ]);


    res.send({ dailySales });
  })
);



export default orderRouter;
```

DashboardScreen.js

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Chart from 'react-google-charts';
import { summaryOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';


export default function DashboardScreen() {
  const orderSummary = useSelector((state) => state.orderSummary);
  const { loading, summary, error } = orderSummary;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(summaryOrder());
  }, [dispatch]);
 

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="line">
      </div>
    <div className="background">
      
    <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox />
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <>
          
          <div className="graphs">
           <div>
            <h2 className="graphname">Daily Sales</h2>
              {summary.dailySales.length === 0 ? (
                <MessageBox>No Sale</MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <Chart
                  width="100%"
                  height="400px"
                  chartType="AreaChart"
                  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                  data={[
                    ['Date', 'Sales'],
                    ...summary.dailySales.map((x) => [x._id, x.sales]),
                  ]}
                ></Chart>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first question: in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#configuration-options) for react-google-charts, there is a configuration option called: vAxis.minValue, described as:

Moves the min value of the vertical axis to the specified value; this will be downward in most charts. Ignored if this is set to a value greater than the minimum y-value of the data.

I'm betting this will help you out. In the docs, there's also an example of implementation:

```
vAxis: {minValue: 0}
```